# What house provides the best means to level enchanting and smithing

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the best house locations in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42962/where-are-the-best-house-locations-in-skyrim)

Playing the part of the warrior I don't have either Dark Brotherhood's sanctuary or the Archmage room (and I've read Companions won't give your *cool* room). For this reason, I have to buy a house where to store my valuables. Unfortunately, Breezehome doesn't sport an Enchanting table, but there's a smelter nearby...

So where to buy a house so that I can train/use both enchanting and smithing effectively?

Answer (score 1):

You got an enchanting table in Dragon's reach in the wizard's room...

Comment: Unfortunately a bit far away...

Comment: @Emanuele You can fast travel to Dragon's Reach as soon as you step out of Breezehome. That's what I do right now.

Comment: @chandsie he doesn't mean that he means when you are in the palace, you have to run all the way up to the court wizards room and use the enchanting table.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the other available houses have Arcane Enchanters, but none have forges or smelters.  Riften's does have a tanning rack and there is a blacksmith nearby.  That might be your best bet.

Comment: I was thinking about that one too... I'll just forget the smelter then...

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer SOLITUDE "IMHO" since it has close and easy access to all things needed.
here is a link that covers Enchanting & Smithing and all the things you might not have considered and how they intermingle,yes this link covers more but once you start on
those 2 many other facits pop up,like it takes money to make money,to buy items just to
disenchant them and so on. it is exactly what i have done and continue to do.
hope this link helps :)
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/41934/15734

this link walks you through getting the Solitude house for FREE,thought i'd add this
as a bonus in the spirit of sharing the Skyrim Love :)
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42197/15734